# access hidden attributes of a class in python

Tags: python

demonstrates the way to hide the attributes of class and method to access the hidden variables outside the class

```
class hiding():
    # class attribute, "__" befor an attribute will make it to hide
    __hideAttr = 10
    def func(self):
        self.__hideAttr += 1 
        print(self.__hideAttr)

a = hiding()
a.func()
a.func()


#AttributeError: 'hiding' object has no attribute '__hideAttr'
print (a.__hideAttr)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Accessing a hidden attribute results in error, comment out the below line to remove the error:

```
print (a.__hideAttr)
```

To access hidden attributes of a class, use:

```
print (a._hiding__hideAttr)
```

Comment: Yeah, My search didn't yield the expected result. Hence posted this.